# question about meaning of indistinguishable in an example in stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, measure-theory

I have a question about example 3.4 on Page 6 of the document here:
http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/862Winter06/Handouts/revised_lecture1.pdf

My specific question is that I understand stochastic process $X$ and $Y$ are the same "version". However I don't quite understand why they are NOT indistinguishable.

The definition of indistinguishable in Definition 3.3. says that they are indistinguishable when $P(X_{\alpha} = Y_{\alpha} \forall \alpha \in I) = P(\{w\in \Omega : X_{
\alpha}(w) = Y_{\alpha}(w) \forall \alpha \in I\})=1$

I think it means that the set that constitute $\Omega$ has to satistifies the condition of $P(X_{\alpha} = Y_{\alpha}$) for every single $\alpha$. So for every single $\alpha$, we have that condition of $P(X_{\alpha}(w) = Y_{\alpha}(w)) $ for all the w  that has non-zero measure in $\Omega$ I guess. Is  my understanding correct?

Then if so, could someone explains why the X and Y in Example 3.4 are not indistinguishable?

Because isn't it true that no matter what z is generated from $Z \sim N(0,1)$, we have $X_t=0$. And $Y_t$ is also zero? So we have for each $t$, the set of z that makes $X_t=0$ and $Y_t=0$ at the same time is actually all the element in set of Z? So all element z in Z in the normal distribution satisfies the $X_t(w)=Y_t(w)$ condition? so shouldn't this the Definition of 3.3 equals to 1 now?

IF someone could explains this example, could you also explain Exercise 3.5 as to why they are not indistinguishable too?

Thanks

Comment: Hi: I'd like to see a formal ( and better) answer than I can give but I think the idea is that the first probability considers a specific individual value of $t$ while the indistinguishable probability considers the set for all $t$ which is a much larger set. Once you consider the larger set, $abs(Z)$ has to equal to $t$ for some $t$ so it's not zero.  But hopefully someone else will explain it more clearly. There's a similar example in Billingsley that I've always wondered about so thanks for great question.

Answer (score 2):

In case the link ever breaks, here is a summary of the examples in question:

> **Example 3.4.**
>   Let $Z$ be an absolutely continuous random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.
>   Define the stochastic processes $X$ and $Y$ on $[0, \infty) \times \Omega$ by $X_t = 0$ for all $t \geq 0$ and
>   $$
> Y_t =
> \begin{cases}
> 0, &\text{if $t \neq |Z|$}, \\
> 1, &\text{if $t = |Z|$}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Then $Y$ is a version of $X$ (i.e., $P(X_t = Y_t) = 1$ for all $t \geq 0$), but $X$ and $Y$ are *not* indistinguishable (i.e., it is *not* the case that $P(\text{$X_t = Y_t$ for all $t \geq 0$}) = 1$).

*Proof that $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable.*
To show that $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable, we must show that $P(\text{$X_t = Y_t$ for all $t \geq 0$}) \neq 1$.
In fact, we can show the stronger statement that the event
$$
A = \{\omega \in \Omega : \text{$X_t(\omega) = Y_t(\omega)$ for all $t \geq 0$}\}
$$
is empty. This will imply that $P(A) = 0$, so in particular $P(A) \neq 1$.
Indeed, suppose $\omega \in \Omega$.
We will show that $\omega \notin A$.
Let $t = |Z(\omega)|$, which is some number in the interval $[0, \infty)$.
Then $X_t(\omega) = 0$ (since $X_t$ is identically zero), and $Y_t(\omega) = 1$ (since $t = |Z(\omega)|$). In particular, $X_t(\omega) \neq Y_t(\omega)$, so $\omega \notin A$. Since $\omega \in \Omega$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that $A = \emptyset$, and we are done.

---

**Note.** This proof did *not* require assuming that $Z$ was an absolutely continuous random variable; this assumption was only used in the proof that $X$ and $Y$ are versions of each other.

---

> **Example 3.5.** Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$, $\mathcal{F}$ the completetion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to Lebesgue measure, and $P$ the uniform/Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{F}$.
>   Let $X$ and $Y$ be the stochastic processes on $[0, 1] \times \Omega$ be given by $X_t = 0$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$ and
>   $$
> Y_t(\omega) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1, & \text{if $t = \omega$}, \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise} \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   for all $t \in [0, 1]$ and $\omega \in \Omega$.
>   Then $Y$ is a version of $X$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable.

*Proof that $Y$ is a version of $X$*.
Fix $t \in [0, 1]$. Then $\{X_t \neq Y_t\} = \{t\}$, so $P(X_t \neq Y_t) = 0$.

*Proof that $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable.*
To show that $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable, we must show that $P(\text{$X_t = Y_t$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$}) \neq 1$.
In fact, we can show the stronger statement that the event
$$
A = \{\omega \in \Omega : \text{$X_t(\omega) = Y_t(\omega)$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$}\}
$$
is empty. This will imply that $P(A) = 0$, so in particular $P(A) \neq 1$.
Indeed, suppose $\omega \in \Omega$.
We will show that $\omega \notin A$.
Let $t = \omega$, which is some number in the interval $[0, 1]$.
Then $X_t(\omega) = 0$ (since $X_t$ is identically zero), and $Y_t(\omega) = 1$ (since $t = \omega$). In particular, $X_t(\omega) \neq Y_t(\omega)$, so $\omega \notin A$. Since $\omega \in \Omega$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that $A = \emptyset$, and we are done.

---

**Note.** I copy-and-pasted the last proof above from the first example, making only minor changes. Both proofs use a similar "diagonalization" argument.

Comment: Hello, in your answer to Example 3.4, when you wrote $Y_{z(w)} (w) = 1$ for every w in $\Omega$, what is the reason for that? Is it because the probability that a normally randomly distributed variable equal to a particular single value has probability zero? so that is why z(w) is never equal to w for a given w?  Because when I was trying to understand that example, the author says P(|z|=w)=0 by saying P(z=w) + P(z=-w) = 0, so I assume it is because a continuous random variable has probability of zero equal to a particular single value. Is it your reasoning of writing that $Y_{z(w)} (w) = 1$?

Comment: Also do you assume your z(w) is bigger than or equal to zero only? because the time index has to be non-negative, is it correct? So should there be absolute sign around the z(w)?

Comment: There were indeed missing absolute value signs, thanks for catching that! The reason $Y_{|Z(\omega)|}(\omega)=1$ is because of how $Y$ is defined

Comment: Hello, but how do you know $Z(w) = w$ ? I thought Z is a random variable, so it might not be equal to w. So when Z(w) not equal to w, I thought $Y_{z(w)}$ then is no longer equal to 1. Isn't it?

Comment: Let's say w is 0.68, how do you know Z will equal to 0.68? I thought Z is random, and also can Z equal any particular number say 0.32, 0.5, 0.1, 0.68 with a non-zero probability? (i.e. P(Z=0.32) or P(Z=0.5) or P(Z=0.1) , can they be greater than zero? or have to be strictly equal to zero?) . I thought P(Z=0.32) = P(Z=0.5) = P(Z=0.68) = 0 ?  is it correct?

Comment: Because when the Y is defined, it is not defined to be 1, it is defined to be 1 or 0 depending on whether t equals to w I thought.  And I think t doesn't have to equal to w, the W is a normally distributed random variable I thought.

Comment: Could you explain little bit more about why $Y_{z(w)}(w)=1$?

Comment: @john_w. hopefully, artem will answer but I think that the idea is the following:  P is uniform so, by definition,  $\omega$ is between $0$ and $1.0$. Then, since $t$ goes from $0$ to $1.0$, over all $t$,  there has to be a $t$ and a $\omega$ for which $w = t$. So, the probability equals one even though, for a specific $t$, the probability  equals zero.

Comment: yes it seems w=t for some t in [0,1] is "possible", but isn't the probability is zero?Because in the author's explanation to Example 3.4 when he talked about "X and Y have same version", he used $P(Z=t) + P(Z=-t)=0$, so he means that Probability of Z equals to a particular t is zero.

Comment: @john_w sorry for the delay; I added some details in the answer

Comment: @Artem Mavrin: I understand much more clearly now. In fact, the proofs to both examples look even more similar to each other than they did previously. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Marvin, but in Example 3.4, the first sentence it says "Let Z be an absolutely continuous random variable on a probability space ..."

Comment: @john_w yes, that assumption is used to show that $Y$ is a version of $X$, but it is not needed to show that $X$ and $Y$ are not indistinguishable